# If $f$ and $g$ are differentable functions with $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $g'(0) \neq 0$, show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x) } =\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

Tags: calculus

I am having a horrible time with this, my Professor does not do any examples in class at all and I am a visual learner and could use some help. This is for a review and I would like to avoid L'Hopital's and the MVT is possible. I just can't seem to figure out how to prove it without *g'(0)=0*

Comment: This is called L'Hopital's rule. Most calculus textbooks should include a proof of it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansions? If so what happens if you expand those two functions around 0? What terms can be neglected in the limit as $x $ tends to zero?

Comment: Taylor's theorem will do it, but it's a bit stronger than you need. You will only need the first order approximation, so the mean value theorem is sufficient.

Comment: This is for a review of chapter 3 we didn't get to L'Hopital's or the Mean Value Theorem until chapter 4 so I didn't want to use them and I'm not familiar with the Taylor Expansion.

Comment: Plug in definitions on the rhs, and use $f(0)=g(0)=0$.. That should at least make the claim plausible. Then try to get an exact proof out of that. If you have trouble doing that, ask a concrete question that shows that you have done some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \dfrac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\\
\dfrac {f'(a)}{g'(a)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \dfrac {f(x) - f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\\
f(a) = g(a) = 0\\
\dfrac {f'(a)}{g'(a)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}$